# crontab not able to trigger job at morning but other time works fine. Mac setting issue?

Tags: macos, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have schedule a job in crontab for every workday morning 8 am, but it didn't triggered. I have checked the folder **/var/mail/** and no log found.

But when I change this time like after  2 min or 5 min from current time, it start working and can see the log in **/var/mai**l after execution.

Do I need to change any setting in my iMac ? is it something like, OS going to sleep mode and not able to activate itself ? or something else.

As a new user of Mac really struggling for almost everything :(

**crontab**

`Tests-iMac:~ testautomation$ crontab -l
    0 8 * * 1-5 /Users/testautomation/Documents/Automation/Schedule/Execute.sh`

**Execute.sh file code**

`#!/bin/bash
    cd /Users/testautomation/Documents/Automation/TFS/Mem_Mobile
    pwd
    /usr/local/bin/tf get -recursive -force -all -overwrite -login:xxx,yyyy
    /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/bin/mvn clean install
    /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/bin/mvn exec:java
    echo "#########################################################" 
    echo "##############       End Execution       ################"
    echo "#########################################################"`

Comment: cron jobs don't run when the system is asleep (and cannot wake it up), so if it's asleep at 8am, that'd explain it. You could do a scheduled wakeup a little before 8 (in System Preferences -> Energy Saver pane -> Schedule button). Alternately, you could create a [launch agent](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/launchd-examples-launchd-plist-file-examples-mac) (or daemon, if it needs to run as root and/or when nobody's logged in), using the `StartCalendarInterval` key; that still won't run while it's asleep, but will the next time it wakes up *after* a missed run.

Comment: thanks... yes it was because hard "put hard disks to sleep when possible" was enabled ... I switched it off by untick the checkbox and now working fine